# How to view image full screen in panoramaGl,it is shows corner of the screen in android

Tags: android, panoramas

```
public class PanoramaGLActivity extends PLView
{
/**init methods*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Load panorama
    PLSpherical2Panorama panorama = new PLSpherical2Panorama();
    panorama.getCamera().lookAt(30.0f, 90.0f);
    panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.spherical_pano), false));
    this.setPanorama(panorama);

}
```

### result screen:

https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSZ82iDt2EMnlR71VHe0-vdMp2JnUcaW2RGYVHK_trXzvrkNwphQ

How to display in  full screen?

Comment: Fixed the problem by setting    kMaxDisplaySize = 2048; in PLConastants class in panoramaGL

Comment: Make your activity full screen in manifest  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"